# Can't add resources in jar generated by scalac

Tags: scala, compilation, nullpointerexception, resources, scalac

I have file in with an SQL query, which I need to run using SparkSQL. Since the file is too big, I don't want to copy it straight into the code.

```
.
├──_main.scala 
├──_resources 
│  └── query.sql
```

Howewer when I compile it

```
scalac -cp "<path-to-resources>/*:<jars path>/*" -d "main.jar" main.scala
```

and try to run, it throws NullPointerException when I try to call "mkString"

```
val queryIt = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("query.sql"))
val query = try queryIt.mkString finally queryIt.close()
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mujd6.png)

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: @GaëlJ With spark-submit

Comment: Can you share the command? The thing is compiling with the SQL file in the resources is useless, you have to provide the file at runtime.

Comment: @GaëlJ spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client main.jar <args>

Comment: Is there no way to include file in jar to use it in spark-submit?

Comment: Oh yes my bad the file can be included in the JAR. Have you checked it is? Unzip the jar and look at its content.

Comment: It contains only
>META-INF
>main.class

Comment: Why are you using `scalac` directly instead of using **sbt** / **maven** or any other build tool?